# Can I buy GTX 750ti or GTX 950 for my HP Compq pro 6300 microtower

Tags: graphics-cards

I'm not sure If I can buy one of these Cards for My [HP Compq pro 6300 microtower](https://support.hp.com/hr-en/document/c03382665) :
GTX 750ti  or  GTX 950

I'm not Hardware expert, But I think that there must be enough space for the card, and that the power supply should be sufficient, And I'm not sure of these 2 points.

N.B The computer is in its original state ( I mean no modification or addition have been done to it) So any reuired info about the model is as in its [factory specs page](https://support.hp.com/hr-en/document/c03382665)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 6pin GPU power connector coming out of your power supply, you can do 950, but else, buy a 750ti

Your power supply should be strong enough to hanlde both of these cards, but the gtx 950 has an extra power connector. So if you don't have that availible, the 950 won't be compatible :((all possible gpu's for that pc don't have 6pin power, so it could be that you don't have that)

Comment: How to know If I have this 6pin GPU power connector?

Comment: Just check the cables coming out of your power supply